# how to use fadeInUp animation on slider's text ,when user clicks next-slide button, with html , css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

I want animate the text in my slider , to fadeInUp,
I have use slider, when user clicks on the next slide button, next slide text will run the fadeInUp animation , How do i do it? i did try to do it with animate.style (https://animate.style/), but the issue is that it only run the animation on load , i want to run the animation when user click the next-slide button to see another slide, how can i do it with css and javascript or jquery ? can anyone help me in this? pls your help will be much appreaciated. Thank you!!,  here is my html slider code

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Swiper demo</title>
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
        />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"
        />
   </head>
<body>
     <!-- Swiper -->
     <div class="swiper mySwiper">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="slide-container">
               <div id="slide-ani" class="slide-info">
                   <h1>REIMAGINE GROWTH 1.</h1>
                   <span>Scaling exponontially,not linealy</span>
                   <span>Powered by digital</span>
               </div>
               <div class="slide-img-section">
                 <img src="./Images/image1.jpg" class="slide-img" alt="slider1"/>
               </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="slide-container">
              <div class="slide-info">
                  <h1>REIMAGINE GROWTH 2.</h1>
                  <span>Scaling exponontially,not linealy</span>
                  <span>Powered by digital</span>
              </div>
              <div class="slide-img-section">
                <img src="./Images/image2.jpg" class="slide-img" alt="slider1"/>
              </div>
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="slide-container">
              <div class="slide-info">
                  <h1>REIMAGINE GROWTH 3.</h1>
                  <span>Scaling exponontially,not linealy</span>
                  <span>Powered by digital</span>
              </div>
              <div class="slide-img-section">
                <img src="./Images/image1.jpg" class="slide-img" alt="slider1"/>
              </div>
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="slide-container">
              <div class="slide-info">
                  <h1>REIMAGINE GROWTH 4.</h1>
                  <span>Scaling exponontially,not linealy</span>
                  <span>Powered by digital</span>
              </div>
              <div class="slide-img-section">
                <img src="./Images/image2.jpg" class="slide-img" alt="slider1"/>
              </div>
           </div>
          </div>
    </div>
        <div id="swiper-button-next" class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div id="swiper-button-prev" class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
      </div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
     

      <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
    <script>
        var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
          loop: true,
          slidesPerView: 1,
          // autoplay: {
          //   delay: 1500,
          // },
          navigation: {
            nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
            prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
          },
        });
      </script>
</body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cdns were not proper. I have added some css with proper cdns. You can have a look:

**Edit**: *Please ignore the images that i have used in the code. I have just add some random images path from the internet just to check if fade effect is working properly or not*

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  speed: 500, // Speed in milliseconds.
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
  effect: "fade",
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Swiper demo</title>
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
    />
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.5/js/swiper.min.js"
    ></script>
    <link
      type="text/css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.5/css/swiper.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img
              src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dsderm9xw/image/upload/v1604360089/slide4_tqkcha.png"
              alt="Slide 1"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img
              src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dsderm9xw/image/upload/v1604360069/slide3_kxq3pv.png"
              class="slide-img"
              alt="Slide 2"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img
              src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dsderm9xw/image/upload/v1604360048/slide2_e9jntf.png"
              alt="Slide 3"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img
              src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dsderm9xw/image/upload/v1604360030/slide1_agffti.png"
              alt="Slide 4"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        <!-- Add Arrows -->
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```